# Width 100% with postition fixed

Tags: html, css

I have page with sidebars. There is a table. I want to show one line on the bottom of screen, no matter how big the table is. This line should has same width as table does.

Here is what I've tried, but without success:

```
<div style="width: 100%; position: relative;">
    <table>
           ...
    </table>

    <!-- this div will be width as whole page, not as table -->
    <div style="width: inherit; position: fixed; bottom: 0;">Wuah!</div>
</div>
```

Tell me pls some advices how to make it works :) 
Here is a live example, sidebars included: http://other.dttrading.sk/orders.htm

Comment: @amiregelz The problem are the sidebars. If they are added to the page, last line will be wider than a table and will interfere sidebars.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code, including the sidebars?

Comment: @amiregelz here is a live example http://other.dttrading.sk/orders.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fixed` elements are fixed relative to the viewport, not their parent, and they'll will inherit the width from the viewport too. You can check that by inspecting the DOM, the fixed footer has the exact same width as the `<body>`.

One possible workaround:

- Give it `left: 0` to left-align the footer
- Set some `z-index` values so that the footer is behind the sidebar
- Add another container inside the footer, offset it to the right, and center the content inside it.

(Not tested)

Comment: z-index doesn't worked for the position:fixed div - it's always on top

Comment: @PeterDraexDräxler `z-index` can be a little tricky, but it does apply to fixed elements. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SbVUN/).

Comment: can you pls give me tip how to set z-indexes on the live example?

Comment: On the fixed footer: `position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1`. On `#sidebar`: `position: relative; z-index: 2`. The trick is: every element with a `z-index` has to be "positioned" (i.e., must have a `position` value other than `static`).

Answer (score 1):

You should Use the `<div>` that contains the table to format them both and not a seperate one to try to format it to be like the table.

```
<div style="width: 100% position: relative;">
   <!-- this next div is what you should use to format the table and line -->
   <div style ="width: how big you want your table AND line">
    <table>
           ...
    </table>
   </div>
    <!-- this div will be width as whole page, not as table -->
    <div style="width: inherit; position: fixed; bottom: 0;">Wuah!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give me some example please?